# CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist - incorrect file location?

Tags: .net, cryptography, x509certificate

An ASP.NET MVC5 website is making calls to an external SOAP service, these calls need to be signed using an X.509 certificate. I have installed this (.pfx) certificate in the Personal store of the Local Computer via the certificates snap-in of the management console.

The application pool of the website is running under the identity of a domain server account, I have granted this account full control in the `"Manage Private Keys"` option of the certificates snap-in. Also I have copied the certificate to the `"Trusted People"` store.

I have also tried adding this domain service account to the Administrators group, and running the app pool under "Local System", neither solved this issue so it appears that privileges are not the problem.

Using the [FindPrivateKey.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717039.aspx) tool I have located the private key, this is

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\2623f8b3f30bbd9a2b0084d1e6a97132_1e17985d-55d3-4dba-af15-d007f3c2d122
```

and I have granted the same service account full control on this file (and the folder it is in).

However, when trying to use this certificate in code I get an exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist
```

Using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) I notice that the MVC process (`w3wp.exe`) is trying to locate the private key at

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\bfb1e6b28e1ca774d2b42fd7ecb2e023_1e17985d-55d3-4dba-af15-d007f3c2d122
```

so a different path than `FindPrivateKey` found, resulting in `"NAME NOT FOUND"` since this path does not exist on disk.

When using Process Monitor during the call to FindPrivateKey I notice that at first this tool also tries to find a private key at

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\bfb1e6b28e1ca774d2b42fd7ecb2e023_1e17985d-55d3-4dba-af15-d007f3c2d122"
```

but when it cannot find this file it tries again at

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\2623f8b3f30bbd9a2b0084d1e6a97132_1e17985d-55d3-4dba-af15-d007f3c2d122
```

This location exists and is returned as mentioned above.

For both the MVC site as `FindPrivateKey` I am locating the certificate using it's thumbprint, and in both cases I am looking in `StoreLocation=LocalMachine` and `StoreName=My`. The code is using the `PrivateKey` property of the `X509Certificate2` class.

Questions about private keys and this specific exception come up more often, and I have tried the answers that are suggested for those question, but unfortunately without success. What can be the problem? Why does `FindPrivateKey` come up with a different (apparently correct) private key location than the code?

Comment: "Questions about private keys and this specific exception come up more often, and I have tried the answers that are suggested for those question, but unfortunately without success" ... which ones did you try and why didn't they return success?

Comment: As mentioned above, I have set (full control) permissions on both the file location returned by FindPrivateKey, the containing folder, and via the "Manage Private Keys" option in the certificates snap-in. I have verified that these permissions are granted to the correct account using the Process Monitor log, although I have also tried granted 'Everyone' full control on these locations.But I think the problem is that the path where the application is trying to read the private key is incorrect, I have no idea why this path is different from the path returned by FindPrivateKey...

Comment: The application pool is not running as "network services" but a domain service account. Possibly this account does not have enough permissions, but as mentioned above I have granted full control to the private key, perhaps other permissions are needed?

Comment: I don't personally know the answer to this, my experience with the MS API's is limited; I've already upvoted the question, there's not that much more that I can do...